# Metric on $T^*M$ with positive injectivity radius and making the fibers totally geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, riemannian-geometry

Consider the cotangent bundle $T^*M$ of a compact riemannian manifold $M$. My goal is to find a metric $g$ on $T^*M$ such that it has positive injectivity radius and the fibers are totally geodesic . After thinking about this problem for a long time here is an attempt.

Consider the canonical decomposition of $T_{(x,v)}T^*M=H(\theta)\bigoplus V(\theta)\cong T_xM\oplus T_xM$ in horizontal and vertical components, given by a riemannian metric $\tilde g$ on $M$.  Now let's define a metric $g$ on $(x,e^tv)$ where $|v|=1$.

$$g_{(x,e^tv)}((u_1,v_1),(u_2,v_2)):=e^tg_{(x,v)}(d\phi_{-t}((u_1,v_1)),d\phi_{-t}(u_2,v_2))$$

where $\phi_t$ is dilation by the factor $e^t$ along the fiber.  Due to this condition we will have that sectional curvature of $g$ will be going to zero as $t\rightarrow \infty$, i.e., as the fiber goes to infinity, since we are multiplying by the factor $e^t$ and the sectional curvature on $SM$ is bounded since this is compact. One can also check completeness, and hence this metric has positive injectivity radius. Now we wanna see that the fibers are totally geodesic. But to do this we only need to check a curve minimizing the distance on the fiber also minimizes it on $T^*M$. And this comes from the definition of the Sasaki metric. Therefore the fibers are also totally geodesic submanifolds.

I wanted to get some insight on this to see if there is any mistake that I am making. Any insight is appreciated, thanks in advance.